# Android Parse SDK i/o failure unknown format (magic number 227b)

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to recover my records from Parse. The class is called Rating. When I try to find less than 5 records, there are no problems. But when I try to find more records, the next stack is shown:

```
com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure
at com.parse.ParseRequest.newTemporaryException(ParseRequest.java:289)
at com.parse.ParseRequest$2.then(ParseRequest.java:144)
at com.parse.ParseRequest$2.then(ParseRequest.java:138)
at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:839)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: unknown format (magic number 227b)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:101)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:81)
at com.parse.ParseDecompressInterceptor.intercept(ParseDecompressInterceptor.java:40)
at com.parse.ParseHttpClient$ParseNetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(ParseHttpClient.java:147)
at com.parse.ParsePlugins$1.intercept(ParsePlugins.java:115)
at com.parse.ParseHttpClient$ParseNetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(ParseHttpClient.java:147)
at com.parse.ParseHttpClient.execute(ParseHttpClient.java:122)
at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:135)
at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:132)
at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:839)
at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:830)
at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:642)
at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:653)
at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:745)
at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:733)
... 4 more
```

Anyone has any clue why this is happening?

Comment: I started to have problems with queries 2 weeks ago too

Comment: This is a confirmed bug. It will be fixed in the 1.13.0 version. For now, you can rollback to 1.11 or add the `ParseLogInterceptor`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make it work I am using the 1.11.0 version ( compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0' ). So far no problems.

Comment: This was the only solution for now. Obviously a bug in their code.

Comment: Perfect man, worked for me. I was writing my question here at SO for this issue. I've been struglling with that for 2 weeks now.

Comment: I had the same issue and this worked for me. Downgraded from 1.12.0 to 1.11.0. Must be a bug in 1.12.0 for sure.

Comment: In version 1.13.0 it's already fixed. Prefer to use compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'

Answer (score 3):

I have the same bug but with me the query work fine with Android Api +19 , older versions throws this exception

Comment: same here! why is it happening though?

Comment: I just started getting this as well... no solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class ParseLogInterceptor

```
public class ParseLogInterceptor implements ParseNetworkInterceptor {
@Override
public ParseHttpResponse intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
  ParseHttpRequest request = chain.getRequest();

  ParseHttpResponse response = chain.proceed(request);

  // Consume the response body
  ByteArrayOutputStream responseBodyByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  int n;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  while ((n = response.getContent().read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
    responseBodyByteStream.write(buffer, 0, n);
  }
  final byte[] responseBodyBytes = responseBodyByteStream.toByteArray();
  Log.i("Response_Body", new String(responseBodyBytes));

  // Make a new response before return the response
  response = new ParseHttpResponse.Builder(response)
      .setContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(responseBodyBytes))
      .build();

  return response;
 }}
```

Add this before Parse.initialize():

```
Parse.addParseNetworkInterceptor(new ParseLogInterceptor());
```

It works for me.

Source: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/325

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Parse `1.12.0`. I opened an issue on their repository at https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/355 - the developers have reproduced it and are working on a fix.

As others have mentioned, the current workaround is to simply fallback to `1.11.0`, or to compile against API19 or above.